# Positioning cells in fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

I am just getting started with fphp and have managed to get the pdf document as I want it with just one problem. I currently have this:

[image: Bars]

and the code I use to get it is:

```
$pdf->MultiCell(0,5, "Feedback: " ."",0, "J");
$pdf->SetFillColor(185, 44, 146);
$pdf->Cell($obsObservation1,5,"",0,1,1,"L", "true");

$pdf->MultiCell(0,5, "Challenge: " ."",0, "J");
$pdf->SetFillColor(197, 198, 200);
$pdf->Cell($obsObservation2,5,$currentY,0,1,1,"L", "true");
```

I would like to have both bars to the right of the text and with the left sides in line. Is this possible?

I realise that I should perhaps not be using cells but I can't seem to find the correct alternative.

Comment: It might be worth reading this related post: [fpdf cell positioning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153612/fpdf-cell-positioning)

Answer (score 0):

Dont use multicell...

Just do plain cells....

PS : This probably wont work right as Ive typed it, but its something along these lines....
Play with it, and you'll get it. :)

```
$pdf->SetY(0);
$pdf->SetFont("Arial","B","13");
$pdf->SetXY(5, $pdf->y + 5);
$pdf->Cell(5, 5, "Feedback :");

$pdf->SetY(0);
$pdf->SetXY(15, $pdf->y + 5);
$pdf->Cell($obsObservation1,5,"",0,1,1,"L", "true");


$pdf->SetY(0);
$pdf->SetFont("Arial","B","13");
$pdf->SetXY(5, $pdf->y + 15);
$pdf->Cell(5, 5, "Challenge :");

$pdf->SetY(0);
$pdf->SetXY(15, $pdf->y + 15);
$pdf->Cell($obsObservation2,5,"",0,1,1,"L", "true");
```